# How to match a text with newlines after a word using bash

Tags: regex, grep

I need to match the end of a file after a word match in bash.
I have a text like this:

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
key line
line 5
line 6
```

I pretend to get everything after "key line", so my output would be:

```
line 5
line 6
```

How can I do this using bash?
I've tried  `grep -o -P '(?<=key line\n)[\s\S]*'` but it didn't work, although it worked testing in https://regexr.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grep` is line-based. It doesn't work well when you want to search across lines.

`sed` is up for the job. This will `d`elete all lines from line `1` to the one containing `key line`, leaving only the lines after it:

```
$ sed '1,/key line/d' test.txt
line 5
line 6
```